# Remove all hyperlinks in a text file, linux scripting

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I am very new in scripting, but I want to learn it.
What I have to do is to remove all occurrences of something like http://* from a text file. I want to do it with sed command and regular expressions.

Here is what I have come up to so far:

```
sed 's/http:\/\/.*/ /' < input.txt > output.txt
```

This code replaces all the hyperlinks with a space. But the problem is that it also removes the rest of the line.

How can I fix this problem? I have tried adding space, "http://.* " or end of word "http://.*\>" or other tricks that I found in the internet, but they didn't work.

And is there a better way to do so instead of using sed?

Answer (score 0):

Sed is a fine way to do this. Try changing your regex to `s!http://[^[:space:]]*! !g`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked.
But could you tell me why     s!http://[^s]*! ! didn't work (it caused strange things) and what is the g for?

Comment: @Nima: The g flag in sed stands for "global". It basically means "match all instances of the input regex in the pattern space". By default, sed only changes the first instance of the pattern on each line (and some versions replace the whole line, as yours apparently did). Adding the 'g' flag makes sed replace the pattern everywhere it is found in the line.

Comment: @NimaPourdamghani also, `\s` which I originally had in the regex is a PCRE character class. sed uses POSIX regex, not PCRE.